# Is there an appropriate weighted Sobolev space to include exponential map and projection map?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, contraction-mapping

Observe that given a non negative function 
$\omega: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$, we can define the weighted 
$L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^2, \omega) $ spaces. They are measurable functions 
$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that their weighted $L^p$ 
norm is finite i.e., 
$$ \int |f|^p  \omega d \mu  < \infty.  $$
Similarly, we can define the weighted Sobolev spaces 
$W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^2, \omega)$. They are the completion with respect 
to the weighted $L^p$ norm of the spaces  of $k$ times 
differentiable functions that have finite weighted Sobolev $p$-norm. 
Now consider the linear operator 
$$ T: W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^2, \omega) \rightarrow W^{k-1,q}(\mathbb{R}^2, \omega)  $$ 
given by 
$$ T(v(x,y)) := \frac{\partial v(x,y)}{ \partial x}.$$ 
My question is as follows: does there exist some weight $\omega(x,y)$ 
and integers $k$, $p$ and $q$
such that the following are true:

1) The functions $(x,y) \rightarrow x$, $(x,y) \rightarrow e^x$, $(x,y) \rightarrow y$ and  $(x,y) \rightarrow e^y$ all belong to 
$W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^2, \omega)$ and $T$ maps into 
$W^{k-1,q}(\mathbb{R}^2, \omega)$.

2) The map $T$ is a bounded linear operator.

3) The map $T$ is surjective.

My guess is that
$$ \omega(x,y) := e^{-(x^2+y^2)} $$ 
should do the trick, but I am not certain. The motivation for this question 
is to show that a certain pde has a solution, via the Implicit Function 
Theorem. 
The map $T$ arises as the linearization of some non linear operator.

$\textbf{Remark:}$ If $\omega(x,y) \equiv 1$, then I believe condition 2) 
will be satisfied for appropriate choices of $p$ and $q$. I believe this 
follows from the Sobolev embedding theorem. However the exponential 
function and projection maps are not part of the Sobolev spaces. Hence 
I am considering weighted Sobolev spaces.

Comment: I would think that if $\omega$ is symmetric in $ x$ and $y$ (as your example)  that it cannot satisfy 2) and 3).  No claim of a proof or even any intuition.

Comment: If you forget about condition 1), then the weight $w(x,y) =1$ does satisfy condition 2). That is symmetric. I agree surjectivity may be a problem.